# How to align an image dead center with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap framework and trying to get an image centered horizontally without success..

I've tried various techniques such as splitting the the 12 grid system in 3 equal blocks e.g

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4"></div>
      <div class="span4"><img src="logo.png" /></div>
      <div class="span4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's the easiest method to get an image centered relative to the page?

Comment: And btw. you might want to have a look at the "Offseting columns"-section.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: Someone has flagged this as not an answer, and I agree. Please add this as a comment, and your answer will be deleted shortly.

Comment: ***If you have `img-responsive` class on your `img` tag, the image may not center.***  See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088706/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-center-elements-horizontally-or-vertically/34560589#34560589) for an explanation of why using the bootstrap `center-block` class will solve that problem the bootstrap way.

Comment: If are you using bootstrap, you can do it: stackoverflow.com/a/59469712/4654957

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap v3.0.3 has a class: center-block

> Center content blocks
>
> Set an element to display: block and center via margin. Available as a mixin and class.

Just need to add a class `.center-block` in the `img` tag, looks like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"><img class="center-block" src="logo.png" /></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Bootstrap already has css style call .center-block

```
.center-block {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

You can see a sample from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vxad5/1/)

Comment: the closing `</div>` tag on the `container` div looks missing.  this doesn't work for me on v3.3.7

Comment: with bootstrap only ... you can just wrap the image in a row with **justify-content-md-center** like this:

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <img src="...">
    </div>

Answer (score 151):

The correct way of doing this is

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <img ...>
</div>
```

Comment: this did not work for me when using it on this -http://startbootstrap.com/round-about .. but adding a class `center-block` to the `<img>` elements worked..

Comment: text-center will not work on images with img-responsive class but the comment above ( about center-block) solves this problem

Comment: An observation: In Bootstrap v3.1.0 it is possible to center img-responsive in column by adding text-center to column. This behavior is broken in v3.3.4. Very annoying. Css sucks.

Comment: you should use center-block instead, as said in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Answer (score 140):

**Update 2018**

The `center-block` class no longer exists in **Bootstrap 4**. To center an image in Bootstrap 4, use `mx-auto d-block`...

```
<img src="..." class="mx-auto d-block"/>
```

Comment: Just to add a little explanation to 'Update 2018': mx-auto sets the left and right margins to auto; d-block sets display:block

Answer (score 86):

Add 'center-block' to image as class - no additional css needed

```
<img src="images/default.jpg" class="center-block img-responsive"/>
```

Comment: Not sure why the -1 - THIS IS BY FAR THE BEST ANSWER! It uses the helper class build into Bootstrap.

Comment: In bootstrap 4, use `mx-auto` instead of `center-block`

Answer (score 53):

Twitter bootstrap has a class that centers: .pagination-centered

It worked for me to do:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12 pagination-centered"><img src="header.png" alt="header" /></div>
</div>
```

The css for the class is:

```
.pagination-centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Or maybe `.text-center` class?

Answer (score 37):

You could use the following. It supports Bootstrap 3.x above.

```
<img src="..." alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just what I needed today.

Answer (score 30):

Assuming there is nothing else alongside the image, the best way is to use `text-align: center` in the `img` parent:

```
.row .span4 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in the other answers, you can add the bootstrap CSS class `.text-center` to the parent element. This does exactly the same thing and is available in both **v2.3.3** and **v3**

Comment: Perfect - That does the job.  But say i have a <ul> element below the image...This does not align center as expected, is there anything i can add?  Thanks

Comment: Since .row in one of the core classes in twitter bootstrap. I would recommend to define a new class like on this page http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html with the class masthead.

Comment: @Fixer The `<ul>` should still align center: http://jsfiddle.net/N74N7/1/ There must be other CSS code affecting it

Comment: spent more than 2 or 3 hours and only this line... thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Works for me. try using `center-block`

```
<div class="container row text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4"></div>
      <div class="span4"><img class="center-block" src="logo.png" /></div>
      <div class="span4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I need the same and here I found the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15084576/1140407

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span9 centred">
      This div will be centred.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and to CSS:

```
[class*="span"].centred {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: I think bootstrap people need to add it to their css

Comment: Hi, and thanks! I am using Bootstrap v3 now. I added this to my img container div, so i had to specify the exact width (at least) for my div to make things work. If you have no container or varying image sizes, add this class to your image.

Comment: lifesaver. I had a rather complex style-conflict situation and this is the only solution that worked.

Answer (score 3):

Update 2023. Bootstrap v5.

```
<img src="..." class="mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use following bootstrap class to fix it

```
<img class="mx-auto d-block" src="../path/to/.." alt="Image">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin property with the bootstrap img class.

```
.name-of-class .img-responsive { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems we could use a new HTML5 feature if the browser version is not a problem:

in HTML files :

```
<div class="centerBloc">
  I will be in the center
</div>
```

And in CSS file, we write:

```
body .centerBloc {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

And so the div could be perfectly center in browser.

Comment: Your div's class is called .centerBloc and your css file show's body.loadingDiv ...

Comment: Fixed now @Martin

Answer (score 1):

I am using `justify-content-center` class to a row within a container. Works well with Bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
   <img src="logo.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**IN Bootstarp 5.0**

Use

.mx-auto .d-block

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<div class="row fluid-img">
  <img class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12" src="src.png">
</div>

.fluid-img {
    margin: 60px auto;
}

@media( min-width: 768px ){
        .fluid-img {
            max-width: 768px;
        }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        .fluid-img {
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-right: 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this and added to Site.css.

```
.img-responsive-center {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the above options didn't work for me.
However, this worked!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center;"><img class="center-block" src="img_path" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could change the CSS of the previous solution as below:

```
.container, .row { text-align: center; }
```

This should center all the elements in the parent `div` as well.