# Responsive image align center bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I do a catalog using Bootstrap 3. When displayed on tablets, the product images look ugly because of their small size (500x500) and a width of 767 pixels in the browser. I want to put the image in the center of the screen, but for some reason I can not. Who be will help solve the problem?

[image: Screenshot of part of a product page with the product not centered underneath the headline]

Comment: I like the design of your site and products - nice work `:)`

Comment: Another example of "Why we need place code into question body".

Comment: Try this Boostrap Class in parent element: img d-flex justify-content-center border border-light p-5

Answer (score 587, accepted):

*If you're using Bootstrap v3.0.1 or greater, you should use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20396826/383609) instead. It doesn't override Bootstrap's styles with custom CSS, but instead uses a Bootstrap feature.*

*My original answer is shown below for posterity*

---

This is a pleasantly easy fix. Because `.img-responsive` from Bootstrap already sets `display: block`, you can use `margin: 0 auto` to center the image:

```
.product .img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It's probably better to create a new class with `margin: 0 auto`, rather than changing .img-responsive.

Comment: That's a thought, although personally I can't think of anywhere I'd want a responsive image not centered, especially with this design. It all depends on the use case, and what's going to happen in the future

Comment: Please see this answer if you are using Bootstrap v4 or higher: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293957/4102515

Answer (score 1185):

There is [`.center-block`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L6556-L6560) class in Twitter Bootstrap 3 (*Since v3.0.1*), so use:

```
<img src="..." alt="..." class="img-responsive center-block" />
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as you do not need to add any CSS to use it.

Comment: `class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;"` works for me `class="img-responsive center-block"` does not (bootstrap 3, but a version a few month old)

Comment: Align center does not work when img-responsive is used.

Comment: @DHlavaty can you explain the difference between using .img-responsive AND .center-block and just using .img-responsive with an auto margin like the accepted answer suggests? is one method more robust?

Comment: You might not want to use this if your image is supposed to be clickable.  That is, if it is wrapped inside a `<a href="#"> </a>` pair, the clickable area will get expanded to the full width of the enclosing container which might be quite a bit larger than your image.  This may confuse users who click on what they think is "empty" space.

Answer (score 115):

Add only the class `center-block` to an image, this works with Bootstrap 4 as well:

```
<img src="..." alt="..." class="center-block" />
```

Note: `center-block` works even when `img-responsive` is used

Answer (score 37):

Just use `.text-center` class if you're using Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <img src="..." alt="..."/>
</div>
```

Note: This doesn't work with img-responsive

Comment: The question is about `img-responsive`

Comment: For img-responsive add img-center (tested on 3.3.6) for those that might see this on google searches

Answer (score 11):

This should center the image and make it responsive.

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest a more "abstract" classification. Add a new class "img-center" which can be used in combination with .img-responsive class:

```
// Center responsive images
.img-responsive.img-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply put all the images thumbnails inside a row/col divs like this:

```
<div class="row text-center">
 <div class="col-12">
  # your images here...
 </div>
</div>
```

and everything will work fine!

Answer (score 4):

You can use property of **d-block** here or you can use a parent div with property 'text-center' in **bootstrap** or 'text-align: center' in **css**.

Image by default is displayed as inline-block, you need to display it as block in order to center it with .mx-auto. This can be done with built-in **.d-block**:

```
<div>
    <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="...">  
</div>
```

Or leave it as inline-block and wrapped it in a div with **.text-center**:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <img src="...">  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can still work with `img-responsive` without impacting other images with this style class.

You can precede this tag with the section id/ div id/class to define a order within which this `img` is nested. This custom `img-responsive` will work only in that area.

Suppose you have a HTML area defined as:

```
<section id="work"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="some_image.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Then, your CSS can be:

```
section#work .img-responsive{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Note: This answer is in relation to the potential impact of altering `img-responsive` as a whole. Of course, `center-block` is the simplest solution.

Comment: This answer is under appreciated,  wrapping the image in the row class is crucial in centering the image when there is a text under the image.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code it will work for small icons too with bootstrap 4 because there is no center-block class is bootstrap 4 so try this method it will be helpful. You can change the position of the image by setting the `.col-md-12` to `.col-md-8` or `.col-md-4`, it's upto you.

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-xs-center text-lg-center">
           <img src="" class="img-thumbnail">
           </div>
          </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```css
.img-responsive{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
   margin:0 auto;
}
.Image{
  background:#ccc;
  padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Image">
  <img src="http://minisoft.com.bd/uploads/ourteam/rafiq.jpg" class="img-responsive" title="Rafique" alt="Rafique">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   img {
     display: table;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why `display: table`? It's already `display: block` which is enough to get `margin: 0 auto` to work

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answers already given, having the `img-responsive` in combination with `img-thumbnail` will set `display: block` to `display: inline block`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <img class="img-responsive tocenter" />
</div>
```

.

```
<style>
   .tocenter {
    margin:0 auto;
    display: inline;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="text-align" style="text-align: center;  ">
    <img class="img-responsive" style="margin: auto;" alt="" src="images/x.png ?>">
</div>
```

you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

> You can fix it with defining margin:0 auto
>
> or you can use col-md-offset also

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.img-responsive{
margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Image</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <p>The .img-responsive class makes the image scale nicely to the parent element (resize the browser window to see the effect):</p>                  
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236"> 
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The more exact way applied to all Booostrap objects using standard classes only would be to not set top and bottom margins (as image can inherit these from parent), so I am always using:

```
.text-center .img-responsive {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I have also made a Gist for that, so if any changes will apply because of any bugs, update version will be always here:
https://gist.github.com/jdrda/09a38bf152dd6a8aff4151c58679cc66

Answer (score 0):

So far the best solution to accept seems to be `<img class="center-block" ... />`. But no one has mentioned how `center-block` works.

Take Bootstrap v3.3.6 for example:

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

The default value of `dispaly` for `<img>` is `inline`. Value `block` will display an element as a block element (like `<p>`). It starts on a new line, and takes up the whole width. In this way, the two margin settings let the image stay in the middle horizontally.

Comment: also float:none requires

Answer (score 0):

**2021.09 from a project**:

```
                    <div class="d-flex" style="height: 60px; width: 60px;">
                            <img alt="ddd" src="myurl" class="m-auto"/>
                    </div>
```