# How to center an image within a col element in bootstrap 3+

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been struggling to center a few images since moving to Bootstrap 3. Previously, I'd use pagination-centered class on the whole col element but that does not work now.

In addition, I've tried creating the class img-center to use margin: 0 auto ([per the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462808/responsive-image-align-center-bootstrap-3)) but that is not working either and I'm unsure why. If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-center" src="images/chart_bw.png">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Charts & data</h3>
                    <p class="text-center">Polish your analytical skills by picking apart Marimekko, bar charts, regressions & more</p>
                </div><!-- col-md-4 -->

                <div class="col-md-4 pagination-centered">
                    <img class="img-center" src="images/calculate_bw.png">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Mental math</h3>
                    <p class="text-center">Nail your mental math by practicing on unlimited case style math problems</p>
                </div><!-- col-md-4 -->

                <div class="col-md-4 pagination-centered">
                    <img class="img-center" src="images/lightbulb_bw.png">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Case problems</h3>
                    <p class="text-center">Structure problems and compare answers to suggestions from McKinsey consultants.</p>
                </div><!-- col-md-4 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div> <!-- col-md-10 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- container -->
```

---

```
.img-center{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You've missed the `display: block;` declaration.

Comment: adding "center-block" to the image is not work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<img>` is not a block-level element. You need to set `display: block;` to the `<img>` to get `auto` left/right margins to work.

```
.img-center {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or use [`.text-center`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L495-L497) class for the *parent* element (the column in this case) to align the inline(-block) elements such as `<img>` center horizontally.

There's also a helper class called [`.center-block`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L5639-L5643). You could use that to align the `<img>` element:

```
<img class="center-block" src="images/lightbulb_bw.png">
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually Bootstrap have class ready for centering some element. Just add class "center-block" to the image class.

```
<img class="img-center center-block" src="images/chart_bw.png">
```

Here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/RVD48/1/