# Centering Divs on Bootstrap Responsive Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I'm using bootstrap grid as shown below and I'm trying to centralize some divs. ( [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv394.png)). I've tried everything {margin:0 auto; width:50% } etc etc but I can't work it out. It can't be that difficult to centralize some divs. What's the problem here? Please don't mark it as a duplicate. I've been researching the whole day, I just can't work it out.
Thank you

```
<header data-spy="affix" id="myHeader" class="container row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                <div class="centralize">
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                        <img class="logos" src="images/facebook.png" onmouseover="zoomin(this.id)" onmouseout="zoomout(this.id)">
                        </a>    

                        <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank">
                        <img class="logos" src="images/twitter.png" onmouseover="zoomin(this.id)" onmouseout="zoomout(this.id)">
                        </a>    

                        <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
                        <img class="logos" src="images/instagram.png" onmouseover="zoomin(this.id)" onmouseout="zoomout(this.id)">
                        </a>

                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="centralize">
                        //Other Stuff to be centralized 
                </div>
            </div>                  
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="centralize">
                        //Other Stuff to be centralized 
                </div>
            </div>          
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually with {margin:0 auto; width:50%} it should work.

But in your code I see that you are using the .col-sm-4 class on the parent div that only takes 1/3 of the width. It might work with .col-sm-12 instead that takes 100%

Comment: Sir, I wanna center stuff INSIDE the col-sm-4 divs.

Comment: Bootstrap already has the ".text-center" class (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) so I don't see reasons to add another "centralize" class. You could even add it to the  ".col-sm-4" divs and remove the inner <div>

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi I thought it only worked for... text. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 0):

To center align the content within the `class="centralize"` divs, use:

```
.centralize {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. I wanna center stuff INSIDE the col-sm-4 divs!

Comment: I suggested the same or similar in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462808/responsive-image-align-center-bootstrap-3?rq=1). If the OP is using Bootstrap 3.0.1 or newer (they don't specify), you should [use the `.center-block` builtin instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20396826/383609)

Comment: @RyanGee Thanks sir.