# How to keep images at the centre of a div? row text-centre and margin-auto did not work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have images with **different widths** that need to keep them **at the centre
of their respective divs**.

I need to **consider all margins- top, bottom, left, right. They should be at the centre of the divs not top-centre. Therefore `class="row text-centre"` and `class="center-block"` wont help.**

I tried to change the margins but having different width per image made it impossible. I am wondering if there is any way to keep any image with any width at the centre of its div.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/4wz688o1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<style>
.col-md-3.img-container {
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    -ms-flex-flow: column;
    flex-flow: column;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.img-div {
    -webkit-box-flex: 2;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    -ms-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
    //position: relative;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right:20%;
//  margin:auto;

}
</style>
</head>


<body>


    <div id="wrapper">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3 img-container">
                    <div class="img-div">
                        <a
                            href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQiWGXo4U6CCvNItlDYFgEQz4d3T-YjLj13nqUZ-crpAr3qMPx-"
                            title="" data-gallery rel="nofollow"> <img
                            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQiWGXo4U6CCvNItlDYFgEQz4d3T-YjLj13nqUZ-crpAr3qMPx-"
                            width="20%" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive img-adv" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 img-container">
                    <div class="img-div">
                        <a
                            href="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSqUIWjfSNC02M5Yjo-7nLBoeSJSEcOZCy0uRdF7Z8HgZRxGWB_Lg"
                            title="" data-gallery rel="nofollow"> <img
                            src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSqUIWjfSNC02M5Yjo-7nLBoeSJSEcOZCy0uRdF7Z8HgZRxGWB_Lg"
                            width="40%" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive img-adv" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 img-container">
                    <div class="img-div">
                        <a
                            href="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTP96P2l57b9znJ60v1gYS695LfH9K0bt8lB38Yi0McCdtq_dtC"
                            title="" data-gallery rel="nofollow"> <img
                            src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTP96P2l57b9znJ60v1gYS695LfH9K0bt8lB38Yi0McCdtq_dtC"
                            width="80%" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive img-adv" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 img-container">
                    <div class="img-div">
                        <a
                            href="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYUsrUfG7vmoT61NjkXL1o-Xk-I032GQI1wuZ_QIcen399srHimA"
                            title="" data-gallery rel="nofollow"> <img
                            src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYUsrUfG7vmoT61NjkXL1o-Xk-I032GQI1wuZ_QIcen399srHimA"
                            width="90%" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive img-adv" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>




</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989238/center-align-image-within-div-horizontally and many many others? Including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879955/how-to-align-an-image-dead-center-with-bootstrap)

Comment: @vogomatix the titles are the same but the required answers are not.

Comment: yes they are: add class="center-block"

Comment: @vogomatix add center-block to which part? I used row text-centre but did not work.

Comment: to the img element. Also why are you putting "width=20|40|80|90%" in the img elements?

Comment: @vogomatix that set the images at the top centre of their divs. They need to be at the centre. I need to consider margin-top and margin-bottom as well.

Comment: @vogomatix because each should have its own specific width. I have to show them in different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap

```
class="center-block"
```

### Just add center-block class to the image , that will do the trick << didnt work

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

With this class MUST be centered in both dimensions. Take a look, you must add this class to the image within the a tag :

[image]

Comment: Thanks but thats useful to set margin-left and margin-right. how about margin-top and margin-bottom?

Comment: So try with this class

Comment: `.Absolute-Center {   margin: auto;   position: absolute;   top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; }`

Comment: Does not work. You may try it in my fiddle.click on demo link.

Comment: @Jack , try with my edition ,  if doesn't work sorry , i didn't understand the question.

Comment: Great thanks, lets see if someone comes up with a better idea otherwise I would accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align:center;
```

add this to `.img-div`

Comment: how about margin top and bottom?

Comment: add line-height : 400px; to the container class

Comment: I did but they are not at the centre yet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4wz688o1/5/

```
.img-div:before {    /* create a full-height inline block pseudo=element */
content: ' ';
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
height: 100%;
}


.img-div {
height: 400px;
-webkit-box-flex: 2;
-webkit-flex: 2;
-ms-flex: 2;
flex: 2;
position: relative;
text-align:center;
}

.img-div img {
vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
}
```

Essentially the img-div needs a proper height to operate on.

Edit: based on Srinivas Pai fiddle and an earlier StackOverflow submission
[image]

Comment: Thanks, they look great in the fiddle but are not aligned in the browser.

Comment: I tried on Firefox and Safari.

Comment: They're aligned in Firefox and Chrome - I don't know what those width statements are doing but they are blowing the bottom two images up beyond the 400px height of the div and should go. Remove them and use CSS styling instead.

Comment: The reason that I have them is that I need need each image has a specific width because I do not want to show them in their actual sizes nor in the same size. I reckon the reason that it did not work for me is that I did not remove the width of images. What should I do, if I want to keep images at the centre of their divs and show them with different widths.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. You don't need any ::before and img styles.

```
.img-container{
   position: relative;
   /* set some width and height, I test with width: auto, 100%, 800px and fixed height */
   display: table;
}

.img-container .img-div{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have removed `margin` and added `text-align:center;`

Try this

```
.img-div {
    -webkit-box-flex: 2;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    -ms-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center; // added this
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wz688o1/1/

Updated code

```
.img-div {
    -webkit-box-flex: 2;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    -ms-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
    position: relative;

}

.img-div img
{
     position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4wz688o1/4/

Comment: I used that but need to have them at the centre of their divs. (margin-top and bottom are also important)

Comment: Please check your fiddle. They are not at the centre of their divs.

Comment: @Jack Now please check updated fiddle.

Comment: @Jack I changed previous fiddle and added updated fiddle is that not working for you?

Comment: I had a look at your fiddle top three images are not aligned.