# how can i show this picture in center in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

how can i show this picture in center in bootstrap?
i'm new to bootstrap. thanks.

[image]

```
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-8 mx-auto"  id="fotodiv">
        <img src="img/lgo.png" class="img-fluid" >
      </div>
```

Comment: I think you can add the classes "d-block" and "mx-auto" to the img element.

Comment: Follow this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879955/how-to-align-an-image-dead-center-with-bootstrap. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Horizontal alignment**

Simply add `text-center`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8 mx-auto text-center"  id="fotodiv">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0R2W.png" class="img-fluid" alt="oppo">
    </div>
<div>
```

Both vertical alignment and horizontal alignment

```
d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center
```

```css
#fotodiv{
  height:250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"  id="fotodiv">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0R2W.png" class="img-fluid" alt="oppo">
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, OP is asking for vertical alignment

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try. It's good for centering content.

```
.form-group {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your containing div as a flexbox, with `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content: center` for vertical alignment:

```css
#fotodiv {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh; /*or 100% of your outer container*/
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; /* horizontal alignment */
  justify-content: center; /* vertical alignment */
}

img {
  /* just to see the image's borders */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8 mx-auto"  id="fotodiv">
    <img src="img/lgo.png" class="img-fluid" >
</div>
```