# Centering text in a table in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, The text inside the table still is not centered. Why? How do I center the text inside the table?

To make it really Clear: For example, I want "Lorem" to sit in the middle of the four "1".
​

```css
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
table,
thead,
tr,
tbody,
th,
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Lorem</td>
      <td colspan="4">ipsum</td>
      <td colspan="4">dolor</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeCpZ/)

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The `.table td` 's text-align is set to left, rather than center.

Adding this should center all your `td`s:

```
.table td {
   text-align: center;   
}
```

---

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
table,
thead,
tr,
tbody,
th,
td {
  text-align: center;
}

.table td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Lorem</td>
      <td colspan="4">ipsum</td>
      <td colspan="4">dolor</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Updated JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JeCpZ/1/)

Comment: In later versions there a text-center class for this.

Comment: beware: .table td { text-align: center; }  will center ALL your TDs

Comment: @xr09 Yes there is, `.text-center`, but the specificity of `.table td` will still defeat it. This is why bootstrap should have started with tagnames instead of launching directly into classes like `.table`

Comment: Add ``.texter-center`` in the ``<table>`` and all rows will become centered.

Comment: @chaim comment should be posted as an answer. Worked on bootstrap-vue 2.0.1

Comment: @chaim, I guess it is `.text-center`

Answer (score 217):

In Bootstrap 3 (3.0.3) adding the `"text-center"` class to a `td` element works out of the box.

I.e., the following centers `some text` in a table cell:

```
<td class="text-center">some text</td>
```

Comment: I liked this solution over changing the entire .table td style.

Comment: You can also just add class "text-center" to table element.

Comment: This is the real answer.

Comment: Worked great in bootstrap 5.3. Is there a similar way to *vertically* center the cell contents as well? EDIT use `<tr class="align-middle">`

Answer (score 46):

I think who the best mix for html & Css for quick and clean mod is :

```
<table class="table text-center">
<thead>
        <tr>                    
        <th class="text-center">Uno</th>
        <th class="text-center">Due</th>
        <th class="text-center">Tre</th>
        <th class="text-center">Quattro</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

close the `<table>` init tag then copy where you want :)
I hope it can be useful 
Have a good day
w stackoverflow

p.s. Bootstrap v3.2.0

Comment: while this question already has answer,there is no meaning of posting new answer!!

Answer (score 32):

You can make td's align without changing the css by adding a div with a class of "text-center" inside the cell:

```
    <td>
        <div class="text-center">
            My centered text
        </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, in Bootstrap 2.3 the `td {text-align:left}` will override any additional attempts to center things.  I just attempted doing it this way, with no success.

Answer (score 17):

```
<td class="text-center">
```

and fix .text-center in bootstrap.css:

```
.text-center {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: I believe you do not want to directly change bootstrap.css.

Comment: I did not need to fix .text-center in bootstrap.css, this worked without it.

Answer (score 8):

If it's just once, you shouldn't alter your style sheet.
Just edit that particular `td`:

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
```

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and a better way to solve it without using `!important` was defining the following in my CSS:

```
table th.text-center, table td.text-center { 
    text-align: center;
}
```

That way the specifity of the `text-center` class works correctly in tables.

Answer (score 4):

One of the main feature of Bootstrap is that it alleviates the use of !important tag.
Using the above answer would defeat the purpose. You can easily customise bootstrap by modifying the classes in your own css file and linking it after including the boostrap css.

Answer (score 4):

add:

```
<p class="text-center"> Your text here... </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

just give the surrounding `<tr>` a custom class like:

```
<tr class="custom_centered">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

and have the css only select `<td>`s that are inside an `<tr>` with your custom class.

```
tr.custom_centered td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

like this you don't risk to override other tables or even override a bootstrap base class (like some of my predecessors suggested).