# How to add an existing class to td in css file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I want to apply the `text-center` class from Bootstrap to all the `td` cells in my table. But I **do not** want to do this for all 40 `td`s: `<td class="text-center"></td>`

Obviously this doesn't work;

```
#mytable td {
    text-center; //class already exists
}
```

So how do I apply this class to my `td`s in a css file?

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that you don't not want to manually write `class="text-center"` into all of the `td`s?

Comment: @AlexanderLomia Yes I think that's what he means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering text in a table in Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678298/centering-text-in-a-table-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: wondering if any of the answers helped..!

Comment: thanks for selecting the ans, please upvote too if it was helpful :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not in pure `CSS`.

You can do this in `LESS`, like this:

```
#mytable td {
    .text-center;
}
```

Or you can also use jQuery to add class to your current td elements

```
$('#mytable td').addClass('text-center');
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you don't want to write the desired class into all of the `td`s one by one. Instead, you can always use the **Search and Replace** functionality of your editor (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> in PHPstorm in this case):

[image]

Using other methods like JS or additional CSS would be an unnecessary waste of resources at best and would introduce confusion in your code at worst.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add the class by hand, you can write a script like

JavaScript

```
var tdList = document.querySelectorAll('#mytable td');
[].forEach.call(tdList, function(el){
  el.classList.add('text-center');
});
```

jQuery:

```
$('#mytable td').addClass('text-center');
```

If not, you can achieve similar effect by adding the following in CSS:

```
#mytable td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

Also, if you use a smart text editor like sublime or brackets which support multiple cursors, you can simply select all `<td>` using mouse and write `class="text-center"` just once. For example in brackets you can do so by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking the place where you want to add cursor.

If you install an extension like [emmet](https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet), you can simply write

```
#mytable>td.text-center*40
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, you can generate the entire markup. Really, if you're lazy to type... they are lots of ways.

Comment: Why didn't I think of using `document.querySelectorAll('#mytable td')` in my answer. Nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

Since I assume you're using pure CSS, the easiest solution is probably simply copying the code to your stylesheet, unless that violates the license. If you're using a preprocessor, such as SASS, you can use the `@extend .text-center` functionality, which is something I highly recommend.¨

Another solution would be using javascript, but that's not completely reliable.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in css, you can do:

```
#tableId td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

if you don't mind applying centered text to all your cells ( including `<th/>` ) you can apply the `text-center` class in the html:

```
<table class="table text-center">
   ...
<table>
```