# HTML and CSS issue with div structure

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a two-column setup, each with `.col-md-6`. The left `<div>` should have a white background and the right `<div>` a grey one.

They should both sit at 100% height, but the grey `<div>` doesn't want to stretch to the max height. I've set the parent `.grey-right` to relative and the child `.preview-container` to `position: absolute`. What could be wrong?

Also, even though the `.preview-container` looks exactly how I want it to, I just feel like I haven't done a great job coding up the HTML and CSS structure. I've had to use a selector like `.low-margin` as a bandaid fix. Is there a cleaner way to structure the HTML and CSS of this area?

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap CSS which I've referenced in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4211/).

**CSS:**

```
.grey-right {
    background: #eeeeee;
    position: relative;
}
.preview-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60%;
    width: 43%;
    margin: auto;
}
.data-title.low-margin {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="data-title low-margin">Country
    <span class="data-input country-name">USA</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap uses the following grid class [structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827689/is-using-bootstrap-offset-classes-a-correct-method-for-centering-elements/22827904#22827904). Did you mean to type that?

Comment: Thanks @Luxelin it's so hard to see without actually seeing their fiddle. From what I see in the question though, I'm using the correct bootstrap structure with the 50% (.col-md-6) each?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had deleted the comment. I checked afterwards and realized it was fine.

Comment: @Luxelin: Thanks :) was a little confused there. The edit is much appreciated as well, looks much better!