# Bootstrap: How to center a p Element vertically in a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I vertically center this multiple Line p Element in this div while keeping it at the left side of the page?

I tried already to display the parent div as table but this seems to be marked as !important in the bootstrap css.

Thanks!

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <img src="images/pk1.jpg" alt="Telefon">
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <p>asdadadas<br>asdasdasad</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap - how to center elements horizontally or vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088706/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-center-elements-horizontally-or-vertically)

Comment: Im using bootstrap v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using v4, use flexbox!

[Align items vertically with Bootstrap v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <img src="images/pk1.jpg" alt="Telefon">
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 d-flex align-items-center">
        <p>asdadadas<br>asdasdasad</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped! Im gonna be looking deeper into flexbox form now on!

Comment: @Fabian Zbinden it's highly recommended! The power of flexbox makes your markup cleaner and styling more consistent. This is my goto guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <img src="images/pk1.jpg" alt="Telefon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-9 text-center">
              <p>asdadadas<br>asdasdasad</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should review your answer; `.col-*` and `.row` should not be combined in the fashion you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` technique to achieve this vertical center align with single selector.

```
.vertical-center {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

And in markups should add this CSS selector:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3">
  <img src="images/pk1.jpg" alt="Telefon">
</div>
<div class="col-9 vertical-center">
  <p>asdadadas<br>asdasdasad</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            < img src="images/pk1.jpg" alt="Telefon">
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-9 text-center">
            <p>example</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually centers it horizontally AND vertically.