# How can I place my grid container at the very center of my page?

Tags: css-grid

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #9f95df;
}

header {
  min-height: 15vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  background-color: slateblue;
  color: #EEEEFF;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

header span {
  font-size: normal;
  color: red;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  place-content: center;
}

.grid-container div {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>X<span>CodeMedia</span></h1>
</header>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Box 3</div>
  <div class="item4">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

I just want my grid-container class to be `centered vertically` and `horizontal` on the page.

Comment: None of these seems to address my problem

Comment: Can you add your HTML and more details on what you’re trying to center? Is it centering a `grid-container` element in the page? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71594811/centering-elements-in-row-vertically-with-react-bootstrap/71598188?r=SearchResults&s=14%7C30.1391#71598188) Or is it centering item(s) inside the `grid-container`? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536537/centering-in-css-grid?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C308.9017) either way, both problems have a load of already answered questions

Comment: <header>
    <h1>X<span>CodeMedia</span</h1>
  </header>
   <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="item2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="item3">Box 3</div>  
    <div class="item4">Box 4</div>
   </div>

Comment: I want to center the container div on the page. Not the contents

Answer (score 1):

You already use the needed CSS property `place-content: center;` and so the grid is centered horizontally. The reason why the grid doesn't *seem* to be centered vertically is, that the height of the grid is exactly the height of the grid items.

So to fix this, you must increase the height of the grid to the whole page, e.g. `height: 100vh;`. Although in this case this is a bit too large because of the additional header, where `height: 85vh` might be more appropriate:

```
.grid-container {
  /* ... */
  height: 85vh;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #9f95df;
}

header {
  min-height: 15vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  background-color: slateblue;
  color: #EEEEFF;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

header span {
  font-size: normal;
  color: red;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  place-content: center;
  height: 85vh;
}

.grid-container div {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>X<span>CodeMedia</span></h1>
</header>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Box 3</div>
  <div class="item4">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here

    <img src="img/dunya.gif" width="500" height="500" >
                </center>
            </div>
```

integrate this into your own code it should work

Comment: At which a part of my code